# How to overlay a line plot over a bar graph in APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

Right now I have a stacked bar graph and a line graph on one page using apex 'create a  region' functionality. I'd like to combine these to one chart. I am thinking if you pehaps create a custom xml code in order to do so, but i'm not sure if that's the right direction to go to. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to fiddle with XML. Create a second series in the chart using the SQL of your second chart and set the 'Series type' attribute to 'Line'.

Check "Multiple Y-Axis" in the display settings to plot your second series with a separate set of Y values. This means the number range offered in both series can be different scales. This can rescale as you show/hide specific series, as offered in one of the Legend properties.

[image]

Here is a link to a sample application by Hilary from the APEX team, plenty of examples in there regarding what is possible:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=36648

Comment: Wow, thanks! One more thing..The first graph has a much larger range than the line graph. I'd like the line graph to follow it's own y-axis (shown on the right side of the chart) that has a larger scaling through a smaller range, so that everything can be seen nicely. Any ideas?

Comment: This is one of the benefits of using the 2nd y-axis, it chooses the relevant scale for you. Updated answer to include example.